# How to set auto-incremented column in PrimeFaces DataTable?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I want to use PrimeFaces `<p:dataTable>`. I have written this code:

```
<p:dataTable var="v" value="#{bean.dataValues}">

    <p:column headerText="First Column">
       <h:outputText value="" />  
    </p:column>  

    <p:column headerText="Second Column">
       <h:outputText value="value of second column" />  
    </p:column>  

    <p:column headerText="Third Column">
       <h:outputText value="value of third column" />  
    </p:column>  

</p:dataTable>
```

Now I want to get this kind of result in my XHTML page:

```
1. | value of second column | value of third column
2. | value of second column | value of third column
3. | value of second column | value of third column
4. | value of second column | value of third column
```

The first column is very important for me. This column must be auto-incremented and doesn't involve any value of `bean.dataValues`. If the List `bean.dataValues` includes 4 elements, the first column of the datatable must be auto-incremented from `1` to `4` for each value in datatable. How can help?

Thanks !
Marwief

Answer (score 3):

Use the `rowIndexVar` property of `<p:dataTable>` like the following.

```
<p:dataTable var="v" value="#{bean.dataValues}" rowIndexVar="rowIndex">

    <p:column headerText="First Column">
        <h:outputText value="#{rowIndex+1}"/>
    </p:column>

    ...

</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Can I set the rowIndex to a particular property of my bean?